# Sending large data over a java web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, stream

I have a Java web service that returns a large amount of data. Is there a standard way to stream a response rather than trying to return a huge chunk of data at once?

Comment: from a design point of view, you could either throw the whole chunk or request via ajax ... let's say you request 10 posts then you reach the end of the stack , you trigger another request and so on, replace 10 with 10000 , although I'm not sure what you are trying to do ... segmenting big data into chunks is already done by TCP/IP

Comment: a few million json rows ... the obvious question is why !

Comment: I was trying to avoid loading the entire dataset into memory on the server side. If I had multiple users requesting large datasets, trying to load them all into memory to send to the client would cause memory issues.

Comment: As far as the why, I'm just doing some testing and understanding streaming large data from web services. It could just as well be a huge image file or something that I'm streaming chunks of at a time.

Comment: Are you working with SOAP or REST services?

Comment: @JeffStorey not sure if caching might help in this case ... but do clients really need instant access to millions of json rows or do they need acces to it on demand ?

Comment: @ach, they are REST services

Comment: @cristi_b It could be other data rather than json. They could be streaming a large file back from the server.

Comment: @JeffStorey in case your data is only and only text, then ccleve's answer is ok

Comment: Wouldn't the approach largely depend on the format in question as well as the structure of your resources? It's quite a sane approach to require some additional scoping information in order to avoid loading such a huge chunk of data into memory. Alternatively, you could use a dedicated solution. If it's images or videos that you're handling, it would be easy enough to offload the service by redirecting the client to a dedicated server.

Comment: @Tom fair enough, I probably should scope the problem better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is analogous to the older problem with bringing back large RSS feeds. You can do it by parameterizing the request: `http://host/myservice?start=0&count=100`, or by including next/prev urls in the response itself.

The latter approach has a lot of advantages. I'll search for a link that describes it and post it here if I find one.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid putting the work on the client (if possible). It would be nice if the client could just request a single URL and would receive the data in chunks - not sure if that's possible though.

Comment: Depends on your client. Http does support chunking. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Answer (score 2):

I would look into a [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) like approach:

From WIKI:

> Comet is a web application model in which a long-held HTTP request
>   allows a web server to push data to a browser, without the browser
>   explicitly requesting it.

Basically, rather than sending the large data all at once, allow your web server to push data at its own pace and according to your needs.

Comment: I'm not really doing a server push though here. It's still an on demand request from a client.

Comment: No what I meant was once the user does a requests, the server pushes chunks of data at its own pace. Its sort of like a comet because the client doesnt need to request each chunk but is handled by the server

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense. The only thing the client would need is an "end of data" marker or something to know that the transfer is complete.

Comment: The client can know that the transfer has ended when the http connection has been ended.

Comment: it would be good to differentiate between success and an abnormally ended transfer but those are implementation details

Comment: For more information, this can be done using buffers and flushing. I have quickly searched using google. You may want to look at this for an indication: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-cometjava/  Similarly, if you understand PHP, you can get a clearer idea by looking at this: http://w3shaman.com/article/php-progress-bar-script. As for knowing whether the transfer was successful or not, you can store a flag on the server side and perform an ajax call once the http connection has ended. The flag will indicate whether all the information has been sent

Answer (score 0):

Webservice might not be a good method for data transfer.

If I were you, I would like to setup another service like FTP or SFTP.

The server puts the data to the specific path of the FTP server and sends the path information to the client through the webservice response.